# Where can I read the source code for libraries in npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, module

Where can I read the source code for libraries in npm? 
I want to create a module and distribute it. So I want to read other people's code for study.

Comment: in the node_modules folder you can see the code of all the packages you have install. every package has it's own folder.

Comment: you can find the source code also at github. you can find the github page of each package on https://www.npmjs.com. search the pakcage you want on the search bar, click enter, click on the package link and from the right side you could see the link to github.

Comment: @Eliran Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the question.

1. Where can I read source code for the libraries in NPM

Each package in NPM has github link associated with it. For example see following picture.

On the bottom, right, you can see github link for express code. Same convention is followed in all of the packages.
[image]

2. I want to create a module and distribute it.

Here's the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) if you want to distribute your own packages.